# How to avoid overwrite for dictionary append?

Tags: python, dictionary, overwrite

For example, I have:

```
dic={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Now I'd like another `'c':4` add into dictionary. It'll overwrite the existing `'c':3`.

How could I get `dic` like:

```
dic={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'c':4}
```

Comment: You can't have a key in a dictionary twice ... How would you look it up?  What would `dic['c']` return?

Comment: Perhaps [multidict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multidict) might be the data type your looking for.

Comment: Make the values in the dictionary all be lists. That way you can associate more than one value with each dictionary key (which must each be unique).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary keys *must* be unique. But you can have a list as a value so you can store multiple values in it. This can be accomplished by using `collections.defaultdict` as shown below.
(Example copied from IPython session.)

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: d['a'].append(1)

In [4]: d['b'].append(2)

In [5]: d['c'].append(3)

In [6]: d['c'].append(4)

In [7]: d
Out[7]: defaultdict(list, {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3, 4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate keys within a single dictionary -- what behavior would you expect when you tried to look something up?  However, you can associate a list with the key in order to store multiple objects. This small change in your dictionary's structure would allow for `{'c' : [3, 4]}`, which ultimately accomplishes the behavior you're looking for.