# Appending into dicitonary with key and value in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary named data. 
Now I want to append more data to the dictionary. However it seems that I do not append, but overwrite the dictionary. How can I append data?

**Code:**

```
# Add something to data
data = {'level_a_title': 'Disk 1', 'level_a_show_on_analysis_report': '1', 'level_a_type': 'text', 'level_a_value': 'Windows'}

# Add another line for Data
data = {**data, **{'level_a_title': 'Disk 2', 'level_a_show_on_analysis_report': '1', 'level_a_type': 'text', 'level_a_value': 'Backup'}}


# Print everything
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key + ' = ' + str(value))
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dpa\PycharmProjects\json\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/dpa/PycharmProjects/json/main.py
level_a_title = Disk 2 
level_a_show_on_analysis_report = 1
level_a_type = text 
level_a_value = Backup
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Its the property of dictionary. Dictionary always takes latest value for the key. You can save your data with different keys. like {'result1':data1, 'result2':data2}.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid overwrite for dictionary append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846956/how-to-avoid-overwrite-for-dictionary-append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique mapping of keys and values, so `level_a_title`only  map `Disk 1` or `Disk 2`. So if you want to have two value, just like this

```py
data = [{'level_a_title': 'Disk 1', 'level_a_show_on_analysis_report': '1', 'level_a_type': 'text', 'level_a_value': 'Windows'}]
data.append({'level_a_title': 'Disk 2', 'level_a_show_on_analysis_report': '1', 'level_a_type': 'text', 'level_a_value': 'Backup'})

# Print everything
for idx, line in enumerate(data):
    print("Index: ", idx)
    for key, value in line.items():
        print(key + ' = ' + str(value))
```